# Given Δ={r ←p,s; s ← p; p; q←r}, prove that Δ ⊨ q

Tags: logic

Show by using 4 methods:

Definition (M1),
Forward Inference (M2),
Unatisfiability (M3),
Refutation (M4).

that for Δ={r ←p,s; s ← p; p; q←r} q is the logical consequences of delta (Δ ⊨ q)

← is implication here

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**  Definition
So Δ has 4 elements, which makes the table big and complicated (2^4=16 iterations (rows of table)).
As P is one of elements of Δ (P ∈ Δ), any model in Δ set must have 1 (I(P)=1 --> f3=1).
f2=1 => I(S)=1 (ex. S --> 1)
f2=1 => I(R)=1 (ex. R --> 1 or 1)
f4=1 => I(Q)=1 (ex. Q --> 1 )
Because I(P) = I(S) = I(R) = I(Q) = 1, all the elements equal to 1.

So here as we proved all the elements’ values equal to 1 as well as I(Q)=1, we can say Δ ⊨Q.

**Method 2:** Forward Inference
Here we should prove that Δ resolution is sound.
We need 3 steps:
[image: Three steps]

**Method 3.** Unsatisfiability
This method also requires to build a table. However, the number of iterations is still 16. In the method 1 we came to the conclusion that I(Q)= I(P) = I(S) = I(R) = 1 (all the elements equal to 1). Here we care only about I(Q)=1 which is the model for Δ, but the opposite of its value ( ~Q) is not a model of Δ (Δ ∪ {~Q} is unsatisfiable). If it’s unsatisfiable, thus we proved that Δ ⊨Q.

Method 4. Refutation
In the method 2 we have three steps. To make refutation to that method we need to add one more step which will remove the last value

[image: █(Q@Q)/([ ])]

Also can be interpreted as

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXtIr.png]